# Rounded corners for sections in grouped style tableview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uibezierpath

Is it possible to have a tableview with sections that have rounded corners without applying a Bezier path mask to the last cell? The problem with a Bezier path is that it also masks UITableViewRowActions, and makes Delete and Edit buttons invisible, but functional. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Share image what you want to achive.

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can modify fist and last cell corners to give effect of a rounded section.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSUInteger rowsCount = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
        if (1 == rowsCount) {
                cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.f;
                cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        } else {
                if (0 == indexPath.row) {
                        CGRect cellRect = cell.contentView.bounds;
                        CGMutablePathRef firstRowPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
                        CGPathMoveToPoint(firstRowPath, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(cellRect), CGRectGetMaxY(cellRect));
                        CGPathAddLineToPoint(firstRowPath, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(cellRect), 8.f);
                        CGPathAddArcToPoint(firstRowPath, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(cellRect), CGRectGetMinY(cellRect), 8.f, CGRectGetMinY(cellRect), 8.f);
                        CGPathAddLineToPoint(firstRowPath, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(cellRect) - 8.f, 0.f);
                        CGPathAddArcToPoint(firstRowPath, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(cellRect), CGRectGetMinY(cellRect), CGRectGetMaxX(cellRect), 8.f, 8.f);
                        CGPathAddLineToPoint(firstRowPath, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(cellRect), CGRectGetMaxY(cellRect));
                        CGPathCloseSubpath(firstRowPath);

                        CAShapeLayer *newSharpLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
                        newSharpLayer.path = firstRowPath;
                        newSharpLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.f].CGColor;
                        CFRelease(firstRowPath);

                        cell.contentView.layer.mask = newSharpLayer;  
                } else if (indexPath.row == (rowsCount - 1)) {
                        CGRect cellRect = cell.contentView.bounds;
                        CGMutablePathRef lastRowPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
                        CGPathMoveToPoint(lastRowPath, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(cellRect), CGRectGetMinY(cellRect));
                        CGPathAddLineToPoint(lastRowPath, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(cellRect), CGRectGetMinY(cellRect));
                        CGPathAddLineToPoint(lastRowPath, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(cellRect), CGRectGetMaxY(cellRect) - 8.f);
                        CGPathAddArcToPoint(lastRowPath, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(cellRect), CGRectGetMaxY(cellRect), CGRectGetMaxX(cellRect)- 8.f, CGRectGetMaxY(cellRect), 8.f);
                        CGPathAddLineToPoint(lastRowPath, NULL, 8.f, CGRectGetMaxY(cellRect));
                        CGPathAddArcToPoint(lastRowPath, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(cellRect), CGRectGetMaxY(cellRect), CGRectGetMinX(cellRect), CGRectGetMaxY(cellRect) - 8.f, 8.f);
                        CGPathCloseSubpath(lastRowPath);

                        CAShapeLayer *newSharpLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
                        newSharpLayer.path = lastRowPath;
                        newSharpLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.f].CGColor;
                        CFRelease(lastRowPath);

                        cell.contentView.layer.mask = newSharpLayer;
                }
        }
}
```